# Find Index of a Column

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
 $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
getIndex($(this).attr("value").index(this));
}
```

The value of the check box and table header text match. When I click on the cb, I want to get the column index of the table column that corresponds to the cb text and then pass it to getIndex. How do I go about it?

So let us say the checkbox value is "Col1". There is a table column header with the same value "Col1". Similarly "Col2", Col3 and so on. When I click on a cb called "Col3", I want to find the corresponding table column index with the cb text that matches the column header text.

Comment: What column index? You haven't provided any HTML.

Comment: What do you mean by column index? Is this in a table?

Comment: @user1089173 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910753/how-to-get-a-table-column-index-in-javascript-knowing-its-class

Comment: You'll have to query the input's ancestor (ultimately leading to the td) and then call index() on it, or add a custom attribute to your columns and inputs and query it, e.g. <input colid='foo'> which would correspond to <td colid='foo'>. Many ways to accomplish this.

Comment: George, But there isn't a class in my case. I have updated the question to make it clear

Comment: @user1089173 I edited the function slightly and my answer should work. It would be nice if you made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) we could work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getColumnIndexesByValue(value) {
  return $('col[value="' + value + '"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).index() + 1;
  }).get();
}
```